# Best practice for this node.js exception handling approach?

Tags: node.js, exception

I have code with this pattern - I need to call next() both when fn() is successful, or when there is an exception in fn()'s exeuction.

```
try {
    fn.call(obj, a, b, c, function(error, next) {
           ...
           next();
    });
} catch (ex) {
    // log. 
    next();  // This is under question.
}
```

The exception can happen not only in fn, but anywhere in next() also. I shouldn't be calling next() from within the catch, since I don't if the exception came from somewhere during execution of next itself.

So what approach do you folks recommend for this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I recommend you to take a look at [try...catch block description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) (don't mind that it's for browser JS). Is it possible to place `next()` function inside finally block in your case? Is yes I suggest placing it there and taking the whole `try...catch` block inside another `try...catch` block.

Still throwing exception in finalization is not a good practice. Are you sure you are using `try...catch` in the right place? Maybe it's better to do it inside `fn` (or handling wxception inside `error` function)?

Comment: The point is that next() is to be called by fn in usual course, and not by the exception handling. So ordinarily, I do want next to be called as part of regular function call.  But my need is that, if there is an exception, I still need to call next from outside of function call. (It is not an option to handle exception within that function.) To get control over 'next()', I could use Step, but it will be clumsy. Hence the question.